# ajax script onclick alert to popup message box

Tags: ajax, popup, alert

I found this voting script online and was wondering instead of a onclick alert(You already voted) can i change it to a popup message that i can style with css... i have only submitted a part of the code if you need to see more let me know. thanks in advance

```
    function addVotData(elm_id, vote, nvotes, renot) {
  // exists elm_id stored in ivotings
  if(ivotings[elm_id]) {
    // sets to add "onclick" for vote up (plus), if renot is 0
    var clik_up = (renot == 0) ? ' onclick="addVote(this, 1)"' : ' onclick="<a type="button" class="btn" style="width:100%;" href="#test_modal" data-toggle="modal">alert</a>"';

    // if vot_plus, add code with <img> 'votplus', else, if vot_updown1/2, add code with <img> 'votup',  'votdown'
    if(ivotings[elm_id].className == 'vot_plus') {    // simple vote
      ivotings[elm_id].innerHTML = '<h6>'+ vote+ '</h6><span><img src="'+votingfiles+'arrow.png" alt="1" title="vote"'+ clik_up+ '/></span>';
    };
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap modal pop up instead of alert.
[This is well explained example](http://www.whatibroke.com/?p=395)

If you need more help let me know

---

Update

html for model pop up:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="test_modal"> <div class="modal-header"> 
<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a> <h3>Modal Header</h3> </div> 
<div class="modal-body"> <p>Test Alert</p> </div> <div class="modal-footer"> 
<a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a> </div> </div>
```

Html for Button

```
<input type="Button" Text="ShowModal" Id="MyButton"/>
```

javaScript:

```
$( "#MyButton" ).click(function() {
$('#modalName').modal('show');
 });
```

Comment: after googling it it seems bootstrap is just a nice alert box.. is there any way i can have a popup where the mouse is clicked. kinda like a tooltip popping up but only when clicked..

Comment: yup.You can do with boot strap http://l.f.nu/FqY try this link Please dp arefresh on this link.You have to add a buttonlike <a type="button" class="btn" style="width:100%;" href="#test_modal" data-toggle="modal">show alert </a>

Comment: `<div class="modal fade" id="test_modal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
    <h3>Modal Header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Test Alert</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>`

Comment: how do i add the button to the java code? i have updated my code (look above) but alert<a/>"' is showing on the screen.

Comment: No need for adding button like this during on click you can call `$('#modalName').modal('show')` It will show you a modal popup

Comment: so onclick="$('#modalName').modal('show')" then the html in my index and it will show?

Comment: I hope you are gone through doc to use modal popup by bootstrap.You can define a div of your requirement and call the above code in on click.let me know if you need more details.

Comment: i have the bootstrap tooltip going on my site... i just dont know how to call it in the onclick the link you sent me doesnt work....what do i put after the onclick?

Comment: first you have to get the bootstrap modal div.If it's not working try to call in document ready event `Onclick=function(){$('#modalName').modal('show');}`

Comment: thanks i figured it out... dont need the function() in the string :)